# Question about separable polynomials

Tags: field-theory

I have read that for $f \in k[x], k$ being a field, that $f$ is separable if it does not have multiple roots. My question is if the multiples roots must be in the splitting field of $f$ or $k?$

Comment: By definition of splitting field, any splitting field of $f$ contains all roots of $f$.

Comment: I guess this is splitting hairs but what I was asking is what if $f$ has only the root $a$ in $k$ of multiplicity 1. But in its splitting field it has a root $b \notin k$ of multiplicity greater than 1. Would we say that $f$ is separable in $k$ but not in its splitting field. Or would we just say that $f$ is inseparable?

Comment: The concept of $f$ being separable over $k$ relates to the factors of $f$ over a splitting field of $f$, not to the factors of $f$ over $k$. Equivalently, it relates the factors of $f$ in any algebraic closure of $k$.